# Grouping documents in solr

Tags: solr

I want to index orders and corresponding order entries in Solr to display it in our e-commerce site.

I am planning to adopt a De-normalized approach by repeating order details with every order entries to reduce request latency. But at the same time I need to group records by `orderid` to find order total for a specified duration.

Is it possible to achieve this without going for a separate index for orders alone?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, you can user [Result Grouping / Field Collapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) for your query. In your case the group field should be `orderid` and you should add `group=true&group.field=orderid` to your request to Solr  to enable this feature.