# how to segment results in Solr based on field value

Tags: solr

imagine data as follows

```
doc1: url=ibm.com data="a b c"
doc2: url=ibm.com data="b c d"
doc3: url=google.com data="c d e"
doc4: url="google.com" data="d e f"
doc5: url="facebook.com" data="e f g"
```

lets say query is data:c

I wish to get clustered/segmented output on url facet as follows

```
ibm.com {doc1, doc2}
google.com {doc3}
```

I am unable to get this as results. Faceting discussions are all around getting count of matches but not document itself in facet output

Is there any ways I can get this output?

---

Update

Alexander's comment below solved my problem

Comment: You can find answer in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403910/grouping-documents-in-solr

Comment: Thank you so much alxander.. somehow this didnt come in my search results . May be I was looking for wrong words. Thank for your help

Comment: You can vote for this question and answer.

Comment: Hi Alexander.. can you elaborate? How do i upvote your comment? Can you convert this comment into answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted by Alexander in comments

there is a good discussion on same issue at

[Grouping documents in solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403910/grouping-documents-in-solr)